# Can you mount a user's Exchange mailbox with mount.davfs?

Tags: mount, exchange, webdav, davfs2

I know both Sharepoint and Exchange (2000-2007) support WebDav. I can use mount.davfs to mount Sharepoint and even Exchange's public folders. For example:

> *mount -t davfs  https://exchange.mydomain.com/Public -o ro /mnt/exchange*

But I am not able to mount a person's mailbox with mount.davfs with known good credential.
Has anyone had any success with that? I can't find any such cases on google.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out to be pretty easy, the path has to include "Exchange". This is the command to use:

> mount -t davfs https://server.domain.com/Exchange/username -o ro /mnt/mailbox

and put in the username and password credentials.